# How to Manage the permission request code using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-architecture-components, registerforactivityresult

How to Manage the permission request code using Navigation Component?

I referred too many website & stack links, none of it worked, still showing deprecated Waring
[image]

**Google Ref link:**
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#manage-request-code-yourself

**Code:** :Using below code in fragment

```
  private fun checkMultiplePermissions() {
        // check permission first
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // request the permission
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 100)
        } else {
            proceedAfterPermission()  // has the permission.
        }
    }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        myLog("log", "location code : $requestCode")
        when (requestCode) {
            100 -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted.
                    proceedAfterPermission() // permission was granted.
                    myLog("log", "location granted")
                } else {
                    // permission denied.
                    myLog("log", "location denied")
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

**Fragment.kt** : full code

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class FragmentPermission : Fragment() {
    private var binding: FragmentPermisionBinding ?= null

    // Kotlin
    //implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.4"

    //https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#manage-request-code-yourself

    //    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentPermisionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // request the permission
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 100)
        } else {
            //proceedAfterPermission()  // has the permission.
        }
        
        
        return binding!!.root
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        myLog("location3", "location code : $requestCode")
        when (requestCode) {
            100 -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted.
                    //proceedAfterPermission() // permission was granted.
                    myLog("location3", "location granted")
                } else {
                    // permission denied.
                    myLog("location3", "location denied")
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding=null
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the [guide directly above that one](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code)? It shows how to use the non-deprecated APIs.

Comment: i update my full code

Comment: That code is not following the [guide that uses the non-deprecated APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#allow-system-manage-request-code). Have you tried those APIs?

Comment: yes added implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.4" & see this topic : Manage the permission request code yourself : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#manage-request-code-yourself  (referred code)

Comment: Yes, that's the guide for using the old, deprecated APIs...you have to go up one section to the one I specifically linked to if you want to avoid using deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 100)
> ```
>
> This method is deprecated.
> use registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContract, ActivityResultCallback) passing in a ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions object for the ActivityResultContract and handling the result in the callback.

[`requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requestPermissions(java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int)) API is deprecated, and replaced by  [`registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContract, ActivityResultCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,%20O%3E,%20androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)) passing in a `ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions` object
for the `ActivityResultContract` and handling the result in the callback.

First the [activity-ktx](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list#dependency) `build.gradle` module level dependency is needed for the the new API:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-beta01'
```

Then `ActivityResultCallback` callback need to be implemented and passed as a parameter of the [`registerForActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,%20O%3E,%20androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)). This interface has callbacks that handle the user response to the permission request dialog.

To display the permissions dialog, call the `launch()` method on the instance of `ActivityResultLauncher` that is returned by the `registerForActivityResult` function.

So, create an instance of [`ActivityResultLauncher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher) & implement the callback to handle the user response:

```
private val requestPermission =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
        
        if (isGranted) { // Do something if permission granted
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "permission granted by the user")

        } else { // Do something as the permission is not granted
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "permission denied by the user")
        }
    }
```

Then request the permission by using the `launch` function:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        requireContext(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
}
```

**UPDATE**

For requesting multiple of permissions at once: You need to pass array of
permission to launch(). `ActivityResultCallback` returns a `Map<String, Boolean>` with permission as key and its grant status as value:

Then use [`ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions) as follows:

```
private val requestMultiplePermissions =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        permissions.entries.forEach {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
        }
    }

// Usage:
requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
    arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )
)
```

**Applying that on the shared code:**

```
class FragmentPermission : Fragment() {
    private var binding: FragmentPermisionBinding ?= null

    //...
    
    private val requestPermission =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
        
        if (isGranted) { // permission is granted

            proceedAfterPermission()
            
        } else { 
            // handle permission denial 
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentPermisionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        requestPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    } else {
        proceedAfterPermission()
    }      
        
        return binding!!.root
    }

//.... rest of your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

PermissionFragment with NavContoller. Kotlin.

```
 class PermissionFragment : Fragment() {
    private val PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.NFC,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    )
    private var _binding: FragmentPermissionBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val requestMultiplePermissions =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
            permissions.entries.forEach {
                val granted = it.value
                val permission = it.key
                if (!granted) {

                    val neverAskAgain = !ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        requireActivity(),
                        permission
                    )
                    if (neverAskAgain) {
                        //user click "never ask again"
                    } else {
                        //show explain dialog
                    }
                    return@registerForActivityResult
                }
            }
            goHome()
        }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentPermissionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)

        /*don't call this in onCreateView(), NavController has not been created yet
        *
        * don't call this in onResume(), if user selected "never ask again" - checkAppPermission() can go to dead loop after dialog show */
        checkAppPermission()
    }

    private fun checkAppPermission() {
        PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED.forEach { permission ->
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), permission) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
            ) {
                requestMultiplePermissions.launch(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED)
                return
            }
        }
        goHome()
    }

    private fun goHome() {
        val navController = requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you are missing to pass param **Activity** for the function below

```
 public static void requestPermissions(final @NonNull Activity activity,
            final @NonNull String[] permissions, final @IntRange(from = 0) int requestCode)
```

To check that you already have permission if not ask permission.
**in below code instead of this you need to pass your activity.**

```
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this.applicationContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
//already you have permission
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                )
            }
```

to get user response use this.

```
    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -> {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.size > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
// user granted location call your function
                }
            }
        }
    }
```