# Why isn't ActivityCompat.requestPermissions prompting a permission request?

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, android-location

I'm trying to make an activity request for location related permissions by using the code below but when I run the code, it doesn't ask the user for permission for some reason. I added the permissions in the manifest file for both coarse location and fine location. When I open up the activity, it doesn't request the user to enable locations related permissions. I'm not sure why that is and I would appreciate any help.

```
    final int COARSE_LOCATION = 99, FINE_LOCATION = 100;
    ...
    @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION);
                }
    
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, COARSE_LOCATION);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            }
        }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getLastLocation();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ContactListPage.this,"wrong permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
 private void getLastLocation() {
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> locationTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(ContactListPage.this,"Lat: " + latitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(ContactListPage.this,"location was null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        locationTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ContactListPage.this,"error getting last location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Probably they are already granted, or one of them is granted, try to change `&&` to `||` in `onStart()` and debug to make sure you pass into the condition.

Comment: The other thing the requesting permission library is deprecated.. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747784/how-to-manage-the-permission-request-code-using-navigation-component) for the replacement

Comment: I tried changing the and to an or and it still didn't enter the if statement in onstart

Comment: and okay. I will look into the new library

Comment: Are u sure you've added the requested permissions in the mainfest file?